# Getting email from GraphUser with Permissions

Tags: android, facebook

I'm attempting a log-in with FB with the code below. The GraphUser object has first name, last name, ID, but not email. I know I need to add permissions but how do I do it in this case. The permissions are generally added with `Session.OpenRequest` or the LogInButton but I'm not using those. Any suggestions?

```
Session.openActiveSession(activity, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
        // callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                // make request to the /me API

                Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    // callback after Graph API response with user object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            // get email from GraphUser
                        }
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you are able to do a /me request the user must have logged in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the permissions as a parameter in `openActiveSession`:

```
Session.openActiveSession(activity, true, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"), new Session.StatusCallback() {
    // callback when session changes state
    @Override
    public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            // make request to the /me API

            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        // get email from GraphUser
                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I you have more than one permissions then make a list of permissions and call the performPublish() method (where you will be passing that Permission list as parameter) to publish a permission and with that check for the publish permission.

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions", "email");

  private void performPublish() {
          Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
          if (session != null) {
              if (hasPublishPermission()) {
                  postStatusUpdate("name");
              } else {
                  session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS));
              }
          }
      }
      private boolean hasPublishPermission() {
          Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
          return session != null && session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
      }
```

Comment: Actually, in my case you can just add the permissions as a list. Just add the extra parameter with `Session.openActiveSession(activity, this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"), sessionStatusCallback)`